# pandas pivot table with uneven number of entry

Tags: python, pivot

I am trying to transform table (df):

```
area    cat   value
0       A       3
0       B       2
1       A       9
2       A       8
2       B       3
2       C       1
```

to table (df2):

```
area    A     B    C
0       3     2    nan
1       9     nan  nan
2       8     3     1
```

I've tried `df2=df.pivot(index='area',columns='cat',value='value')`
however got the error:

> 'Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional'

It seems that because I have uneven members of `cat` across the index `area`? How would we fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the pivot_table and give columns as cat

```
  df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data))
  print df

   area cat  value
0     0   A      3
1     0   B      2
2     1   A      9
3     2   A      8
4     2   B      3
5     2   C      1

  print pd.pivot_table(df, index=['area'], columns=['cat'])

cat      A    B    C
area
0      3.0  2.0  NaN
1      9.0  NaN  NaN
2      8.0  3.0  1.0
```

Comment: more specifically, `pivot_table` expects sequences of columns, not scalar column names, for the `index` and `column` parameters